# How to get both index and event in v-for and v-on:click?

Tags: vue.js

This is a simple vue demo:

```
<body>
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="text,i in todoList" v-on:click="method_1(i)" >{{text}}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="text,i in todoList" v-on:click="method_2" >{{text}}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el:"#app",
        data:{
            todoList:["aaaaa",'bbbbbb','ccccc']
        },
        methods:{
            method_1:function(i){
                console.log(i) // i is index of v-for
            },
            method_2:function(e){
                console.log(e)
            },
        }
    })

</script>
</body>
```

I want to bind onclick function and put `event` and `index from v-for` as this function's params.

If I use `v-on:click="method_1(i)"`:

-- vue will this take `i` is varibale  of before;

eles if I use `v-on:click="method_1` :

-- vue will automatlly take `click event` as params.

But I want both `click event` and variable of before as my function's params.How can I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To use both events and params, you need to have something like `example($event, params)`

Using your example,

```
<li v-for="(text, i) in todoList" v-on:click="method_1($event, i)">
  {{ text }}
</li>
```

---

```
methods: {
  method_1: function(ev, i){
    console.log(ev) // this is the event
    console.log(i) // i is index of v-for
  }
}
```

Comment: How to deal with customize event with data emited from subcomponent rendered by `v-for`?

Comment: @duXing Just add `native`: `@click.native="your_method($event)"`